# Segmentation Fault when writing to new WAV

Tags: c, file-io, wav

Here's my code snippet that fails:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct WAV {
    char chunkId[4];
    unsigned chunkSize;
    char format[4];
    char subChunk1Id[4];
    unsigned subChunk1Size;
    unsigned short audioFormat;
    unsigned short numChannels;
    unsigned sampleRate;
    unsigned byteRate;
    unsigned short blockAlign;
    unsigned short bitsPerSample;
    char subChunk2Id[4];
    unsigned subChunk2Size;
} WAV;

int main() {
    void printwav(const WAV *);
    void openwav(FILE *, WAV *);
    void makewav(FILE *, const WAV *);

    char file[FILENAME_MAX];
    size_t i;
    short
        stereo1,
        stereo2,
        mono1;
    FILE
        *fpstereo,
        *fpmono;
    WAV
        stereo,
        mono;

    openwav(fpstereo, &stereo);

    printwav(&stereo);

    memcpy(&mono, &stereo, sizeof(WAV));

    mono.chunkSize -= stereo.subChunk2Size / 2;
    mono.subChunk2Size /= 2;
    mono.numChannels /= 2;
    mono.byteRate /= 2;
    mono.blockAlign /= 2;

    makewav(fpmono, &mono);

    printwav(&mono);

    for (i = 0; i < mono.subChunk2Size / sizeof(short); i++) {
        fread(&stereo1, sizeof(short), 1, fpstereo);
        fread(&stereo2, sizeof(short), 1, fpstereo);

        mono1 = (stereo1 + stereo2) / 2;

        fwrite(&mono1, sizeof(short), 1, fpmono);
    }

    fclose(fpstereo);
    fclose(fpmono);
}
```

And my output for the program is:

```
Enter filepath to stereo WAV: wav11stereo.wav
RIFF
1966116
WAVE
fmt 
16
1
2
44100
176400
4
16
data
1966080

Enter filepath to mono WAV: wav11mono.wav
RIFF
983076
WAVE
fmt 
16
1
1
44100
88200
2
16
data
983040

Segmentation fault: 11
```

After testing with a bunch of `printf`s, I discovered the segmentation fault occurs in the line `fread(&stereo1, sizeof(short), 1, fpstereo);` inside the for-loop. I declared `stereo1` as a `short` and not a `short *`, so I don't understand why that's happening. Can anyone explain why that's wrong?

Comment: `fpstereo` cannot change by `openwav`. `void openwav(FILE **, WAV *);` if to allow changes

Comment: IMO, it should be open in the main.

Comment: 'mono1' is still a struct 'WAV'  and a struct does not change size.  so we would need to see the code for printwav() to determine why the output files are the same size.   BTW: the posted code, even after faking the called functions, does not cleanly compile.  One reason is the unused variable 'name[]'  BBTW: the code design needs a bit of work as the stereo handling is all in sub functions while the mono handling is all in main()

Comment: in general, function prototypes should be right after the #include statements, not buried inside some function.

Comment: @user3629249 There is no variable ``name[]``, and ``mono1`` is a ``short``, not a ``WAV``. The for-loop at the bottom is the only portion that manipulates the actual data of the files. Of the two sub-functions, the first one reads the WAV header from the stereo file while the second one writes the WAV header to the mono file, leaving the two ``FILE *`` at the index to begin reading / writing the sound data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess this is your problem:

```
void openwav(FILE *, WAV *);
void makewav(FILE *, WAV *);
```

With this, file open call inside the function will only available inside the function and not returned to the caller.

Normally it should be declared as below:

```
void openwav(FILE **, WAV *);
void makewav(FILE **, WAV *);
```

And call like this:

```
openwav(&fpstereo, &stereo);
makewav(&fpmono, &mono);
```

Comment: okay I added those, and the error is no longer occuring, but my mono file in the filesystem says it's the same size as the stereo file. Shouldn't it be approximately half?

Comment: to debug, maybe you can check return value of both fread(), and print some warning if the return value is zero.

Comment: I found the problem, I was iterating through half the bytes of the stereo file but reading four bytes in every iteration, so I reached the end of the stereo file halfway through the iteration process. I fixed the ``for`` statement in my question but left the code otherwise semantically correct except for the part that was causing the segmentation fault. FYI, ``makewav`` and ``printwav`` do not affect the ``WAV *`` parameters.